# How can I fix User model in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have a custom User model in laravel. But I get errors when relationships with the User model. I couldn't find a similar problem on the internet. I have no idea what to do.
There was no User model before. I was using a model called Account and it was fine. But I updated the model name to User to use laravel's own Auth system.

Error:

```
Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError
Class Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo contains 6 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthIdentifierName, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthIdentifier, Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable::getAuthPassword, ...)

\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo.php:12

class BelongsTo extends Relation implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable {
```

My User model

```php
<?php
  
  namespace App\Models;
  
  use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;
  
  class User extends Authenticatable {
    use HasFactory;
    
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
      'full_name',
      'email',
      'password',
    ];
    
    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $hidden = [
      'password',
    ];
    
    /**
     * Get the blog posts for the user.
     * @return HasMany
     */
    public function posts(): HasMany {
      return $this->hasMany(BlogPost::class, 'id', 'author_id');
    }
  }
```

BlogPost model

```php
<?php
  
  namespace App\Models;
  
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
  use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
  
  class BlogPost extends Model {
    use HasFactory;
  
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var string[]
     */
    protected $fillable = [
      'author_id',
      'thumbnail_id',
      'title',
      'slug',
      'content',
      'description',
      'views',
    ];
    
    /**
     * Get the author for the blog post.
     * @return BelongsTo
     */
    public function author(): BelongsTo {
      return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'author_id', 'id');
    }
  }
```

users table migration:

```php
<?php
  
  use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;
  use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
  use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
  
  class CreateUsersTable extends Migration {
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up() {
      Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('full_name', 64);
        $table->string('email', 64)->unique();
        $table->string('password');
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->timestamps();
      });
    }
    
    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down() {
      Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
  }
```

Comment: Open file `\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo.php` and check if it actually has `class BelongsTo extends Relation implements \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable` because that is not something it should have based on the [source code](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/BelongsTo.php). If it does then delete vendor and run `composer install` again (or just do that first to see if it works)

Answer (score -1):

Try adding the `Authorizable` Trait to the User Model. Don't forget to add the `use` in too

```
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable, Authorizable;
```

Comment: not working....

Comment: @FıratKaya Can you post your updated User class now please. You might need to include

`use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;`